# Issue with ComboBox SelectedValuePath in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, selectedvalue

I am trying to bind a `Dictionary` to my `ComboBox` in a WPF application.

```cs
SortedDictionary<string, string> result = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

((ComboBox)frameWorkElement).ItemsSource = result;
((ComboBox)frameWorkElement).DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
((ComboBox)frameWorkElement).SelectedValuePath = "Key";


((ComboBox)frameWorkElement).MinWidth = 200;
frameWorkElement.Name = "ListOfValues";
var binding = new Binding("ComboBoxSourceValue")
{
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
};
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

frameWorkElement.SetBinding(ComboBox.TextProperty, (BindingBase)binding);
```

In UI side, values are binding properly. But in the submit action, I am able to see only value (`Display value`) only selected value's `Key`.

Comment: Why are you binding the Text property? Bind SelectedValue, and get the value for the key from the dictionary. It doesn't make sense to set SelectedValuePath without binding SelectedValue.

Comment: @Clemens - Thanks for clarification. I have updated binding with SelectedValueProperty, now its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frameWorkElement.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, binding);
```

should work provided that the `DataContext` of the `ComboBox`, or a parent element, is set an instance of a class that has a `string` source property named "ComboBoxSourceValue".

`SelectedValuePath` refers to a property of the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` in the `SortedDictionary`. You still need to bind the value to your source property.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated binding with SelectedValueProperty as you suggested, now its working fine.